# ¿Cómo preguntar si deseo salir de la página?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo hago para que me pregunte si deseo salir de la página o no cuando le doy en la *X* de la pestaña?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var r = confirm("desea salir de esta pagina?");
    if (function window.onbeforeunload) {
        alert("Aceptar");
    } else {
        alert("Cancelar");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

estuve googleando y encontré como evitar que se cierre la pagina, pero por lo que leí no puedes hacer una alerta personalizada. Con el siguiente código el navegador alerta que estas saliendo de la página:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
return "Alerta nativa del navegador";
}
```

[image: Imagen de alerta por defecto de google]

Espero que sirva, saludos